# Auto numbering reset

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel, I'm trying to create an auto number cell based on current year, and next number in sequence.  Example first row in table `14/001`, next row should be `14/002`...

I have formatted my sheet as a table, and the formula I have is `=TEXT(TODAY(),"yy")& "/" &TEXT(ROW(A1),"000")` in cell `A2`.

When I tab across the row in the table, and reach the last cell of the row it defaults to the next row, creates a new row, and copies the formula down, and increments by one just as expected.  That part is working perfectly.

What I don't know how to do is when the years rolls to 2015, how do I reset the `/00`? to `/001` so on January 1 2015 the next row should read `15/001`

Comment: I hope you realize that on the first of January 2015, **all** the cells in your column will switch to *15/xxx*

Comment: Only way I can think of doing that is to have the first row being a "seed" row - without formulae - to allow the formula on subsequent rows to make a text comparison to decide whether or not to reset the counter and increment the year code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    =TEXT(TODAY(),"yy")& "/" &
                    if(left(previous_cell,2)=TEXT(TODAY(),"yy"),
                       TEXT(ROW(A1),"000"),
                       "001")
```

Comment: Won't work - the IF function will always return true, and even if it didn't you'd only ever get "001" on the first row with a year change.  The row after that would revert to showing just the current row number, e.g. 15/001 on Jan 1st then 15/367 on Jan 2nd.

Comment: Wasnt that the required result?

Comment: Personally would've thought the requirement was for 15/001, 15/002 etc.  The If function in your fmla will always return True anyway causing the number to just keep going up and never reset so the point is moot.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are willing to accept a VBA solution, this assumes that the auto-numbers will go in column **A**.  Place the first value in **A1** manually.  Then enter the following *Event Macro* in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim A As Range, oldYr As String, yr As String, N As Long, oldN As Long
    Set A = Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count)
    If Intersect(Target, A) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value <> "" Or Target.Offset(-1, 0) = "" Then Exit Sub
    Cancel = True
    ary = Split(Target.Offset(-1, 0).Value, "/")
    oldYr = ary(0)
    oldN = CLng(ary(1))
    yr = Right(CStr(Year(Date)), 2)
    If yr = oldYr Then
        Target.Value = yr & "/" & Format(oldN + 1, "000")
    Else
        Target.Value = yr & "/" & Format(1, "000")
    End If
End Sub
```

If you double-click on the first empty cell in column **A**, the next auto-number will be entered in that cell.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**